# No se reconoce 'php' como un comando externo o interno

Tags: php, composer

Trabajando en 'php' he tenido que realizar la instalación de 'composer', y es aquí donde me ha surgido el problema, al ejecutar el comando de instalación me ha saltado el error:

 
`"php" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.`

Investigando he visto que tal vez el error estaba en las variables de entorno, a lo que he ido a mirar y efectivamente no estaba bien puesta la ruta de 'php', el problema es que a pesar de esto, reiniciar el equipo para aplicar cambios y demás, sigo teniendo el mismo problema y no entiendo porque sigue pasando a pesar de que en las variables de entorno está bien configurado el 'path'.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las variables de entorno del sistema, la carpeta donde esta php es la misma en la que tengo el xampp instalado, tanto en las variables de entorno de la sesión como las del sistema está de la misma forma

---

SOLUCIÓN ENCONTRADA

Finalmente opte por una solución rápida, aunque tal vez no las más eficiente, hice una copia de seguridad de mis archivos importantes e hice un formateo del disco, de esa manera pude volver a instalar php y no tuve ningún problema

Comment: ¿En que sistema operativo estas?

Comment: Pasa a veces por el tipo de versión que estas usando.
Prueba así: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0M7Tz3PUIrA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0M7Tz3PUIrA)

Comment: El sistema operativo en el que trabajo es Windows 10, a pesar de seguir las instrucciones del vídeo, tengo el mismo problema y es que sigue sin reconocer la ruta de la variable de entorno, a pesar de que es correcta

Comment: Pues muy correcta no será si te da ese error...  deberias pegar lo que has hecho (capturas, más datos) y demostrar que lo tienes bien para que la pregunta sea más precisa y podamos ayudarte mejor... normalmente es una tonteria, pero si nos dedicamos a adivinarla sin más información por tu parte poco acertaremos y será una pérdida de tiempo. Puedes editar tu pregunta pulsando sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta y agregar lo pedido.

Comment: Y de paso mirate este tutorial, a ver si ves algo distinto en tu instalacion: https://devanswers.co/install-composer-php-windows-10/

Comment: ¿Si te pones en la carpeta `c:\xampp\php` y ejecutas un `php -v` desde un terminal (powershell) te sale algo?  Lo digo porque veo en ese enlace que te pasé en el úlitmo comentario que aparece una captura donde, en las variables de entorno, ademas de la ruta del `c:\xampp\php` lo instalan en `c:\php7` (no uso xampp y no tengo ni idea de lo que deberia contener esa carpeta)

Comment: prueba con C:\xampp\php\
A mi me funciono de esa manera